# pandas.DataFrame.loc gives output for a label twice and mentions Name and dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame indexed by item_id (numbers), I tried to access an item at a location by using `DataFrame.loc[str(item_id),word]` where word is the label of the column I want to access. Word is a string:

```
print(output.loc[str(df.loc[i,'item_id']),word])
```

The output I get is the following:

```
hu    0.0
hu    0.0
Name: 17349826, dtype: float64
```

here word has value `hu` and `item_id` had `17349826`.

I want the output as just:

```
0.0
```

Comment: I believe you need `print(output.loc[str(df.loc[i,'item_id']),word]).item()` for convert one element Series to scalar

Comment: `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`.  Got this error, because as you see it gives me the value of hu twice

Comment: So use `print(output.loc[str(df.loc[i,'item_id']),word]).iat[0]` for select first value only.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael !!!You were quick to help. It works perfectly. But can you tell me why I was getting 2 values in the first place.

Comment: It seems is duplicates index values.

Comment: I checked the list of labels. Some of them are duplicates indeed. Thank you @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need select fist value of `Series` by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) for scalar output:

```
print(output.loc[str(df.loc[i,'item_id']),word]).iat[0]
```

And reason for duplicated output is duplicates in `index` values.